# Does whitespace in syntax affect performance in Python?

Tags: python, pep8

When I'm writing code for a personal project, or if I'm just testing things out, I tend to code like this, just because it makes me happy:

```
def importcontacts(request):
  context                       = initialize_context(request)
  context['form']               = UploadedFileForm()
  token                         = get_token(request)

  if request.method == 'POST':
    form                        = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

    if form.is_valid():
      contacts                  = request.FILES['file']
      fs                        = FileSystemStorage()
      filename                  = fs.save('import_data.json', contacts)
      uploaded_file_url         = fs.url(filename)
      context['fails']          = ct.import_contacts(uploaded_file_url,
                                                     token,
                                                     context['user']['email'],
                                                     context['user']['name'])
      messages.success(request, 'Contacts imported successfully.')

      return render(request, 'contactsdb/importresult.html', context)

  return render(request, 'contactsdb/import.html', context)
```

Obviously this isn't in any way PEP8 compliant and I would never put something like this into production but at the same time I don't truly know why and I also don't truly understand why the code even still works when set out like this. I assume all the space makes for slower code?

Googling has not helped me find my answer. I'm not looking for someone to tell me "you should never do that, blah blah", I'm well aware! I'd just like to know the reasons as to why this isn't OK.

Comment: Is it possible for you to copy/paste the code instead of using a screenshot?

Comment: No, the spacing doesn't make your code slower, and yes it's perfectly fine for you to write your code like that. If you have to collaborate with others on the same code, expect a fair bit of annoyance though.

Comment: Ha yeah I can imagine it would drive some people insane. I actually only started doing it as someone I was working with was doing the same thing and it looked so pretty.

Comment: For me, the biggest problem would be when I have to add a definition where the equals sign would be farther to the right than all the others. I'd have to go through and update aaaall of the other definitions. Also, I'd very quickly get annoyed at the number of spaces I'd have to type, not having an easy way for them to snap in place.

Comment: Please don't post images of code, data, or Tracebacks. Copy and paste it as text then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`) ...
[Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: Yes normally I would enter the code as text but as this question was about layout and not actually about the code itself I thought an image conveys what I mean far better. Also if I were to write the code out like that it would not fit on one line and so would make my question quite confusing as the layout would not match what I have on my screen.

Comment: Regarding screenshot vs text code, a compromise would be to wrap the single very long line for the sake of this question, since the topic here is the possible influence of extra white space on performance. I submitted an edit for that --- revert it if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was an interesting question. Basically the use of white spaces between the operands and the operator is to increase readability. It's just a matter of personal choice to add one white space or add ten. The interpreter/compiler doesn't care about white spaces. It's just about readability.

Now when you do something like this-

```
a = 10
b = 100
c = a + b
```

And when you do something like this-

```
a       =          10
b       =          100     
c       =          a + b
```

You'll notice that the first one is more readable than the second one, but this doesn't mean that the second one is wrong. It is just a matter of personal choice. Basically the convention says to follow the first method but we would get the same output with or without white spaces.

So you may use one or ten white spaces in your program, nobody can question you!!

Comment: Good to know thanks! Even though I know Shan's answer is far more in depth, this one makes me happier.

Answer (score 2):

Spacing shouldn't slow down code. Much like any other language, your python scripts get compiled to bytecode and then get interpreted by a virtual machine. The parser usually strips comments and whitespace that isn't indentation or a newline. This [link](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/logical.html) further explains how logical lines are treated:

> The end of a logical line is represented by the token NEWLINE. Statements cannot cross logical line boundaries except where NEWLINE is allowed by the syntax (e.g., between statements in compound statements). A logical line is constructed from one or more physical lines by following the explicit or implicit line joining rules.

and [this one](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/physical.html) explains how physical ones are treated:

> A physical line ends in whatever the current platform's convention is for terminating lines. On Unix, this is the ASCII LF (linefeed) character. On DOS/Windows, it is the ASCII sequence CR LF (return followed by linefeed). On Macintosh, it is the ASCII CR (return) character.

This [link](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/indentation.html) further explains how indentation is treated:

> Leading whitespace (spaces and tabs) at the beginning of a logical line is used to compute the indentation level of the line, which in turn is used to determine the grouping of statements.

And also gives an example of code that is correctly, but strangely indented:

```
def perm(l):
        # Compute the list of all permutations of l
    if len(l) <= 1:
                  return [l]
    r = []
    for i in range(len(l)):
             s = l[:i] + l[i+1:]
             p = perm(s)
             for x in p:
              r.append(l[i:i+1] + x)
    return r
```